# Scrapy FormRequest get stuck

Tags: javascript, parsing, scrapy

I am trying to crawl several urls and for each url several pages and for each page several items. The page change is executed through a FormRequest.
My spider looks like this:

```
def parse_url(self, response):
     for url in url_list:
         yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse_page)

def parse_page(self, response):
     for page in page_list:
         yield scrapy.FormRequest(url,formdata=data, callback=self.parse_item)

def parse_item(self, response):
    for item in item_list:
         yield item
```

I was expecting Scrapy to crawl in the following order:

- url1 - page1: get all items
- url1 - page2: get all items
- url1 - page3: get all items
- url2 - page1: get all items
- url2 - page2: get all items.....

But Scrapy get stuck on the last url in the list and keep changing pages for that url.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Scrapy deals with requests asynchronously so it's unlikely it will scrape in the order you expect. If you limit it to scraping one page, will it scrape everything you expect? Also, if there's an error in one of your routines it's difficult for us to spot from pseudo code, we'll need the URL and xpaths etc..

Comment: To disable this concunrency for easier debugging set `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1` in setting.py or in spider class as class argument `custom_settings = {'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS' : 1}`

Comment: If I limit to just one url, everything works fine : all the pages are visited and all items get scrapped.
But when i add more than one url, it uses only the last one and visits different pages inside the same url.

Comment: CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1 improves the situation. Urls go 2 by 2 and items are scrapped only from the second one. Almost there...

Comment: Actually, I have a strange effect:
- response.url is the right one
- response.body does not match url

Have you ever expierienced this?